# Kofax Line Item Matching Locator

Tags: ocr, kofax

Can someone help me with how can we use Line Item matching Locator.

We Need to validate the Line Item Automatically during Validation.

Comment: Please provide a sample image/document

Comment: Please add a [mcve], list the errors you get, if any. Explain why this code is not working for you and what you expect from it.